# How to model invited users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I am building a RoR application, and I am trying to develop an invitation mechanism, in which users can invite other users by email.
However, I want that if a user already exists in my users table it will reference to it, or, when a non-existing user was invited and he gets registered, I have a reference to it too.

What is the best modelling schema for such scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use 
[devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable)?